# using #!/usr/bin/env python3 shebang with Windows

Tags: python, windows, shebang

I'm trying to run a Python script from the command line as a command on Windows -- so no usage of "Python" or ".py". If my script is named "testing.py", I am attempting to make this name into a command and call "testing" from the command line.

Going through the docs it seems I need to use this shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` as long as I have Python in my PATH.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

I also have the script folder in my PATH, so something like 
"testing.py" is currently working from the command line.

According to the docs and this tutorial, 
https://dbader.org/blog/how-to-make-command-line-commands-with-python

I should be able to evoke my Python script just by "testing" if I have the proper paths within PATH and the above shebang. However, I can't seem to get the script running withouth adding ".py".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Windows does not support shebang lines.

The documentation you've linked relates to the `py` launcher installed by Python, which can interpret various shebang lines to choose a Python version to run a script with.

`setuptools` is able to generate wrapper .exes for your Python scripts, [but it gets a little involved](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) and already assumes you have a package with a `setup.py` and so on.

Locally, if you really, *really* need this, you probably could add `.py` to the [`PATHEXT` environment variable](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt), so the Windows command line looks up `.py`s like it looks up `.exe`s (and various others; the current modern default is `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`). However, this will naturally not scale for distributing apps, as all of your users would need to set that too.

My recommendation is to stick with just that boring old `python testing.py`, really.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer by @AKX is incorrect for Windows 10 standard Python 3, certainly in the latest Windows 10 (1903) if not earlier.

(Note: I cannot speak to how this may or may not work under WSL.)

I have several versions of Python installed (2.7, 3.6, 3.7, and most recently Python 3.8b1). I've been using the `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang for years in my scripts for cross-platform compatibility (usually to distinguish Py2 vs Py3 scripts).

I've created a little script in a folder (`C:\so_test\awtest.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If I run this with `awtest.py` or just `awtest` I get `3.6.x` reported (showing it's running with Python 3.6). If I change the shebang to refer to 3.7, I get `3.7.x` reported. If I change the shebang to just `#!/usr/bin/env python3` I get the latest version of Python installed (3.8).

Now, if I add that folder to my path (`path=%PATH%;C:\so_test` in the command window you're testing in, or in the main env vars (you will need to restart the command window if you do the latter though)), I can change to a different directory and run `awtest` or `awtest.py` and they still work and refer to the folder in the path. If I remove the script folder from the path these files are no longer found.

While I wouldn't necessarily expect this to work on Windows prior to 10 or Python 2.7, this functionality appears to be the way of things going forward.

Comment: Is this under WSL or with a plain Windows Python?

Comment: Regular Windows Python (you cannot use WSL without disabling all other normal virtualization, so I have no way to test it. It's too bad - WSL certainly seems interesting.)

Comment: Ah, right. I took a look – this is because .py has been associated with the Py launcher which can interpret shebang lines in various creative ways: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines – In addition, for just `awtest` to work, `.py` must be in `PATHEXT` on your installation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shebang in windows by setting the path of your interpreter as the first line in the file(you will see a marker on VSCode that says 'set as interpreter ' on that line).
Using windows 10,Python version 3.9 see example:

```
#!C:/Users/waithira/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
print('hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're not going to do this often. You can still add a batch file to your path `testing.bat`  containing the command that you need to execute your code.

```
@echo off
python testing.py
```

It's a borring workaround but it works without needing to mention the extention since windows interpret batch files the same way it interpret executables.