# Remove file from git repository history

Tags: git, github

I checked in (into github) some sensitive files by mistake. To remediate this, I followed the instructions [here](http://%20https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) and ran the commands:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch settings.json" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
echo "settings.json" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add settings.json to .gitignore"
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
git for-each-ref --format="delete %(refname)" refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

I can however go to my commit history to see the deleted file.

To fix this issue, how can I delete the file from github commit history?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have another problem: Since you already pushed the branch with the sensitive material, in between then and now, someone else may have already pulled it.  So, if you get an answer here you should also realize that the cat is already out of the bag in some ways.

Comment: Note that even after you get some commits removed, GitHub will still grant people access to the removed commits as long as they know the hash ID and it has not yet been "too long". It is up to GitHub how long "too long" is: eventually removed commits *won't* be accessible by hash ID.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the repository is a private repository, only I am using the repo.

Comment: @AjitGoel Fair enough, then Von's answer below may completely get you out of the mess.

Answer (score 12):

Try instead to use the best practice is to use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).

---

See "[Path based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES)":

```
git filter-repo --path settings.json --invert-paths
```

Then `git push --force`

No need for all those repack/gc/prune at the end: the tool does the cleanup for you.

Comment: Thank you @VonC, I will try and let you know. i had tried BFG previously but i could not get it to work.

Comment: @AjitGoel Yes, filter-repo should be easier than BFG or filter-branch..

Comment: i am getting a "/usr/bin/env: 'python3': Permission denied" error. I am using windows 10.

Comment: @AjitGoel See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56974927/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603544/6309