# How to make sure python script uses virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I created virtual environment and activate it. 
installed packages but unable to import them from virtual environment.

```
pip freeze:
```

[image]

But getting error trying to import module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\Documents\Python\Projects\ProjectName\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paramiko
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'
```

How to make sure .py file uses virtual environment?

Also if I run

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Result:

```
'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages'
```

So it does not uses virtual environment, is that correct?

Comment: are you running the script from inside your environment? have you verified that `pip` is actually pointing to the `pip` inside your environment

Comment: Thanks. So I activate environment and was able to install module using pip. So I am assuming its pointing to the inside environment. Any other way to make sure?

Comment: @Serdia, your console prompt should contain `(venv)`, like this: `(venv) PC-ForceBru:some_directory forcebru$`

Comment: Yes. It looks like this:   `(GAenv) PS Z:\Documents\Python\Projects\ProjectName\Env>`

Comment: Do I need to keep .py file in `env\Scripts` folder? Cause this seems to be working

Comment: What OS are you on? How do you run your script?

Comment: Using Windows 10 Enterprise. Accessing through VDI.

Comment: In many cases it's not necessary to activate a virtual environment. Typically you could do something like the following from anywhere without activating the virtual environment: `path/to/venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip somecommand`, `path/to/venv/Scripts/python.exe different/path/to/script.py`, etc. Additionally you could specify the absolute path to the `python.exe` as a _she-bang_ at the top of your Python script, and execute the script directly (double-click?) without calling Python explicitly. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Comment: I would also recommend to read the following and to pay attention to really follow this advice: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1):

In many cases it's not necessary to activate a virtual environment. Typically you could do something like the following from anywhere without activating the virtual environment:

- `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip somecommand`
- `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe different\path\to\script.py`
- etc.

Additionally you could specify the absolute path to the `python.exe` as a she-bang at the top of your Python script, and execute the script directly (for example with a double-click) without calling Python explicitly.

```
#!/path/to/venv/bin/python3

print("Hello world")
```

**References**:

- https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Answer (score -1):

You should invoke the `python` that is installed within your environment. That is

```
source myenv/bin/activate
python path/to/script.py
```

In Unix, you would add the following `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script and this would allow you to run it without specifying the `python` binary.

```
source myenv/bin/activate
path/to/script.py
```

Possibly that works in Windows in the [same way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603544/2923406) or [differently](https://superuser.com/questions/378477/making-usr-bin-env-python-work-on-windows).